# Difference in job title, Background check

Tags: resume, background-check, pre-screening

I currently work at a tech company in the engineering department on the database operations team. I do strictly development work in my job, and everyone on my team refers to themselves as software engineers.

I recently applied to and accepted a new job offer, and had “software engineer, database operations” on my resume as my job title for my current role. I recently discovered that my role according to our HR department is actually “database operations engineer”. It seems like the company in general puts the team name then engineer as the title (like devops engineer, web platform engineer, etc). Will this slight discrepancy be an issue for my in the background check for my new position? Should I tell my new company about this or just leave it alone?

Comment: Adding to the system vs payslip vs 'offered' title.  HR uses those titles in many cases for pay scale/pay banding.  They might give you a title for the work you're doing, but it doesn't match what HR can use to determine your pay scale.

Comment: Interesting, didn’t realize it could vary from my payslip title, I’ll have to find out what that is. I get paid via direct deposit and never noticed. I found the HR title just on our internal site where you can request vacation time etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just leave it alone.

Both titles say moreorless the same thing. A reasonable potential employer will think the same

Comment: Makes sense, I felt like it was basically the same as well. My concern was that just database operations engineer sounded slightly different than what I classified myself as but I’m probably worrying over nothing

Comment: Just thought it worth a note, next time check your contract. That normally has your "official" job title on it

Answer (score 1):

> Should I tell my new company about this or just leave it alone?

To be safe you should let them know.  Although what you have on your resume is similar enough to your HR's title ( for any reasonable person ), it is better to give them more information that what they need right now than to have them come back to you and ask you to explain any discrepancies later.